# How and where to store application initialization data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, initialization

I am trying to develop a game using Spring MVC.

For example I have a `Monster` class.

What would be the best way to initialize and store monsters data in spring?

One option is to create all `Monster` instances inside some `Init` java file and make static array so every class can access them, but that seems like a wrong way to go.

Example for Monster : `String name, int hp, int defence, int attack`

On the other hand, should I use XML or properties file to keep all my `Monster` or `Item` information? It would be nice to easily add new `Items` or `Monsters` also in future.

What is the common technology for this kind of work in spring?

I tried to explain as clearly as possible, ask if something is unclear.

Comment: You want to save your monsters + items somehow so that later read them back into your app?

Comment: Basically yes.. well it doesn't have to save them to DB..but like I wonder if there is neat solution for creating and adding new `Monsters` and `Item`, some configuration file maybe...

Answer (score 2):

How about JAXB? See how easy to write config and read it back:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

class Config {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="monsters")
    @XmlElement(name="monster")
    public List<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<Monster>();
}

class Monster {
    public String name = "Test";
}

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Config cfg = new Config();
        cfg.monsters.add(new Monster());
        //save 
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("conf.xml");
        JAXB.marshal(cfg, os);
        // read 
        cfg = JAXB.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("conf.xml"), Config.class);
    }
}
```

conf.xml

```
<config>
    <monsters>
        <monster>
            <name>Test</name>
        </monster>
    </monsters>
</config>
```